# nextUntil() andSelf() wrap()... can't get EACH two elements in list to be wrapped by span?

Tags: jquery-selectors

Working an ajax checkboxlist that generates fine like so but the checkbox and label sometimes break onto a new line and was just trying to do a simple wrap?:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Pet.Color" value="44" id="cbxColor_44" title="Black">    <label>Black</label><input type="checkbox" name="Pet.Color" value="37" id="cbxColor_37" title="Blue"><label>Blue</label><input type="checkbox" name="Pet.Color" value="43" id="cbxColor_43" title="Brown"><label>Brown</label> .....
```

Trying to wrap each input and label in a span, I didn't want to mess up the function that generates each but appending/prepending span here or there, so I was trying for a quick selector to use to wrap() method:

```
 // nope  $('input ~ label').andSelf().wrap('<span class="nowrap" />')
//nope   $('input').nextUntil('label').wrap('<span class="nowrap" />')

//nope $('input').nextUntil('label').each(function (index) {
//    $(this).wrap('<span class="nowrap" />')
// });

// nope  $('input + label').andSelf().wrap('<span class="nowrap" />')
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`andSelf` method](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) simply adds the original element to a set that was selected from it.
For example,  `$(something).children().andSelf()` will select the element's children as well as itself.

You need to loop over each pair and call `wrapAll`:

```
$('input').each(function() { 
    $(this).next().andSelf()    //Get the pair of elements
           .wrapAll('<span class="nowrap" />')
});
```

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure how to indicate you answered it

Answer (score 0):

It so simple:
We insert a tag after or before then select `nextUntil()` or `prevUntil()`

> $("`<li class='aa'>Test</li>`").insertAfter('.bar');
>
> $('.foo').nextUntil('.aa').andSelf().wrapAll("`<p>`");
>
> $(".aa").remove();

```
<ul>
    >     <li class="foo">Baz</li>
    >     <li>Select Me!</li>
    >     <li>Select Me!</li>
    >     <li>Select Me!</li>
    >     <li class="bar">Baz</li>
    >     <li>Don't Select Me</li>
    >     <li>Red Herring List Item</li> </ul>
```

After

> ```
> <ul>
> <p><li class="foo">Baz</li>
> <li>Select Me!</li>
> <li>Select Me!</li>
> <li>Select Me!</li>
> <li class="bar">Baz</li>
> </p>
> <li>Don't Select Me</li>
> <li>Red Herring List Item</li>
> </ul>
> ```